# JSON deserialization query

Tags: windows-phone-7, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON string with the following syntax into C# classes, but I'm sort of puzzled on how to handle the dynamic nature of the "parent" object:

`{"1":[{"id":"12139811","num":"37805729","date":"2012-01-30"},{"id":"12139812","num":"36911026","date":"2012-01-30"}],"2":[{"id":"12158366","num":"17582898","date":"2012-01-30"},{"id":"12207165","num":"38493538","date":"2012-01-30"}]}`

Any help on what the classes should look like will be appreciated.

(Preferably the syntax to Deserialize would be something like

`var objects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyObject>>(jsonString);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think is beacuse your Json star with and identifier "1" instead of the array...
so you could try this

```
var objects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionay<Object,List<MyObject>>>(jsonString);
```

Comment: Yes, that's the point. How would I capture that dynamic start value in a class [JsonProperty] attribute?

Comment: Thats why I use the Dictionary<Object,List<MyObject>> , the Object is  the start value.

Comment: Awesome, misunderstood the first time :) Works like a charm, thanks!